# Метки на Яндекс карте не возможно нажать с гугл хрома, только на андроиде, и то не всех моделях, хотя версии браузера одни и те же

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Все добрый день. Столкнулся с проблемой.

Создаю маркеры на яндекс карте.
Ниже предоставляю код создания яндекс карты с помощью API.
Проблема заключается в том, что метки не кликабельны в гугл хроме и именно на андроиде, и то на нескольких моделях смартфонов. В чем может быть проблема? Подскажите решение? Заранее спасибо)

```
var Ymap = new function() {
    this.map = null;
    this.placemarks = [];
    //this.clusterer = null;
    this.temp_pm = null;
    this.get_doctors_by_spec = function(spec_id) {
        var t = this;
        if (!this.map) {alert('map is not initialized!'); return false;}

    //jQuery("#cuselFrame-map_spec").addClass("classDisCusel");

        $('#maploader').html('загрузка');
        $('#maploader').show();

        // t.map.events
        //         .add('mouseenter', function (e) {
        //             e.get('target').balloon.close();
        //             if (t.temp_pm)
        //                 t.temp_pm.options.set('iconImageHref', '/img/marker.png');
        //         });

        $.getJSON('/doctor/getmap', {'id':spec_id}, function (data) {
            if (!data) {
                alert('Произошла неизвестная ошибка');
                return false;
            }
            for (i=0;i<t.placemarks.length;i++) {
                t.map.geoObjects.remove(t.placemarks[i]);
            }
            t.placemarks = [];


            /*
            if (t.clusterer)
                t.map.geoObjects.remove(t.clusterer);


            t.clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
                // Используем макет балуна кластера "карусель"
                clusterBalloonContentBodyLayout: "cluster#balloonCarouselContent",
                // Используем собственный подмакет для отображения информации о геообъекте
                clusterBalloonContentItemLayout: ClusterBalloonContentItemLayout,
                // Устанавливаем ограничение на количество элементов в нижней панели
                clusterBalloonPagerSize: 5,

                // Установка внешнего вида нижней панели.
                // Режим marker рекомендуется использовать с небольшим количеством элементов.
                 //clusterBalloonPagerType: 'marker',
                clusterBalloonHeight: 'auto',
                clusterBalloonWidth: 'auto',

            });*/
            var BalloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="my_bal_wrap">$[properties.balloonContent]</div><div class="arrow_down"></div>',{
                build: function() {
// исполняем конструктор суперкласса
                    BalloonContentLayout.superclass.build.call(this);
// получает геообъект
                    var geoObject = this.getData().geoObject,
// карту
                        map = geoObject.getMap(),
// координаты геообъекта
                        coords = geoObject.geometry.getCoordinates(),
// контейнер баллуна
                        container =  $(this.getParentElement());
// смещаем контейнер баллуна относительно его привязки, чтобы получилось, что баллун находится по центру над геообъектом
                    container.find('.my_bal_wrap').each( function() {
                            $(this).css( {left: -Math.round($(this).outerWidth() / 2), top: -$(this).outerHeight() - 45});
                            }
                    );
                }
                });
            for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                var pm = new ymaps.Placemark([data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude], {
                    balloonContent: t.get_marker_text(data[i])
                },
                {
                    iconImageHref: '/img/marker.png',
                    //iconImageSize: [45, 45],
                    iconImageSize: [30, 45],
                    //iconImageOffset: [-18, -45],
                    iconImageOffset: [-15, -45],
                    balloonLayout: BalloonContentLayout,
                    balloonAutoPan: false,
                    balloonOffset: [0,0],
                    balloonShadow: false,
                    hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
                    balloonCloseButton : false,
                    balloonZIndex : 5000
                    //hintHideTimeout: 0,
                    //hintHoldByMouse: false
                });
                pm.events
                .add('touchstart', function (e) {
                    // Ссылку на объект, вызвавший событие,
                    // можно получить из поля 'target'.
                    e.get('target').balloon.open();
                    if (t.temp_pm)
                        t.temp_pm.options.set('iconImageHref', '/img/marker.png');
                    t.temp_pm = e.get('target');
                    e.get('target').options.set('iconImageHref', '/img/marker_hover.png');

                    //console.log(e.get('target').style);
                });
                // .add('mouseleave', function (e) {

                //    // t.map.balloon.close();
                //     //pm.balloon.close();
                //     //e.get('target').balloon.close();
                // });



                t.placemarks.push(pm);
                t.map.geoObjects.add(pm);
                //alert(t.get_marker_text(data[i]));
            }


            $('#maploader').html('найдено: '+data.length);
           /* t.clusterer.add(t.placemarks);
            t.map.geoObjects.add(t.clusterer);*/
        })
        .fail(function () {
            alert('Произошла неизвестная ошибка. Попробуйте позже.');
        })
        .always(function () {

        });
    }
    this.get_marker_text = function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        if (data.spec2)
            data.spec1 += ', '+data.spec2;
        if (data.spec3)
            data.spec1 += ', '+data.spec3;
        if (data.patronymic)
            data.name += ' '+data.patronymic;
        var txt = '<div style="width:230px;"><div class="bal_col1"><img class="ym_avatar" src="/files/doctor/small/'+data.image+'" /><p class="bal_col1_price"><span>'+data.price+'</span> <img src="/img/tenge.png" /></p></div><div class="bal_col2"><p class="bal_col2_header"><a href="/vrach/'+data.alias+'">'+data.surname+' '+data.name+'</a></p><p class="bal_col2_spec">'+data.spec1+'</p><div class="rating_ro_wrap"><div class="rating_ro_content" style="width: '+Math.round(data.rating*16)+'px;"></div></div><p class="bal_col2_addr">'+data.address+'</p><div class="btn-write-small" onclick="Request.showForm('+data.id+',\''+data.surname+' '+data.name+' '+data.patronymic+'\')"></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div>';

        return txt;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Какая версия андроида, модель телефона и версия chrome  где метки некликабельны? Кликабельны ли они например тут https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1 ?

Comment: Модель телефона: Samsung Galaxy s9, Версия Андроида; Android Oreo. Версия Хрома последняя доступная в плей маркете. По ссылке что вы скинули метки кликабельны. В целом я думаю проблема такая, что когда я кликаю на маркер, то клик touch воспринимается не как по метке, а как по карте...

Comment: Ваш код достаточно обширен. Давайте внесем минимальные изменения вот в такой пример https://jsfiddle.net/46cL8n2u/ , так чтобы проблема начала воспроизводиться. И тогда я помогу разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

в доке только эти события нашел

```
myCircle.events.add([
    'mapchange', 'geometrychange', 'pixelgeometrychange', 'optionschange', 'propertieschange',
    'balloonopen', 'balloonclose', 'hintopen', 'hintclose', 'dragstart', 'dragend'
], function (e) {
```

Comment: а причем тут эти события? У него даже круга на карте нет.

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geoobject_events - сссылка на события геообъекта, соотсветственно маркер имеет такие же события

к примеру         `myPlacemark.events
                .add('balloonopen', function (e) {
                    console.log('touchstart');
                });`
работает

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/events-docpage/ Вот ссылка. Тут как бы явно приведен пример что по клику можно. И то событие которое у меня стоит, тоже из документации вытащил

Comment: Насколько я вижу там события цепляются к карте. 
Если смотреть реализацию карты, то карта - канва, соответственно, объект, на котором могут работать стандартные события. По ссылке выше приведены события геообъекта. Разница в том, что эти события кастомные и файрятся самой либой, так как геобъекты отрисовываются на канве